# issue while using left join with full outer join

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I have the following code :

```
      Dim rsD As ADODB.Recordset
      Dim sqlD As String
      Set rsD = New ADODB.Recordset
       sqlD = "SELECT A.Role FROM A LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT B.Role From B LEFT JOIN 
            C ON(B.Role=C.Role) 
            UNION ALL SELECT C.Role From C LEFT JOIN B
            ON(C.Role=B.Role))) 
            AS B ON (A.Role=B.Role) WHERE 
            (B.Role IS NULL)"
             rsD.Open sqlD, conn, adOpenStatic
             While Not rsD.EOF
            wb.Worksheets(3).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsD
            Wend

             rsD.Close

    Set wb = Nothing
```

What I want to do:  inner select is for FULL OUTER JOIN so it takes the values from both table B and C and remove the duplicates.
Then the outer select filters out the value which are there in Table A but are not there in Table B and C with the help of left join and NULL.

But i think there is some issue with the outer select due to which proper data is not coming.

Comment: There's probably a more straightforward way to remove duplicates here. What are the table structures, sample data and expected results?

Comment: lets take a example :

Table A :
----------
number
1
2
3


Table B:
----------
Number
1

Table C:
----------
Number
2

expected results : 3

Comment: maybe this will do:

SELECT A.Role FROM (A LEFT JOIN B ON (A.Role=B.Role) WHERE A.Role IS NULL) LEFT JOIN C ON (A.Role=C.Role) WHERE C.Role IS NULL"

But there is some parentheses error i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it, you have 3 tables: A, B, and C.
You want the values of table A that does not exists in B and C.

This is a away:

```
SELECT  A.Role 
FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT B.Role 
                From B 
                UNION 
                SELECT C.Role 
                From C) D ON
        D.ROLE = A.ROLE
WHERE D.ROLE IS NULL
```

Other away:

```
SELECT  A.Role 
FROM A 
WHERE A.ROLE NOT IN (   SELECT B.Role 
                        From B 
                        UNION 
                        SELECT C.Role 
                        From C)
```

or still:

```
SELECT  A.Role 
FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN B ON
        B.ROLE = A.ROLE
    LEFT JOIN c ON
        c.ROLE = A.ROLE
WHERE B.ROLE IS NULL and C.ROLE IS NULL
```

Comment: You are the champ brother. thanx a much